# Linear interpolation given two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Given $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$, the task is to find the value at $x\in (x_0, x_1)$. I know the formula and how to derive it algebraically. Difference in height is $y_1-y_0$, so  $y = y_0 +\dfrac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0) $. No issues so far. Then I thought of rearranging this equation and write it as below  :
$$y = \left(\dfrac{x_1-x}{x_1-x_0}\right)\color{red}{y_0} +\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}\right) \color{red}{y_1} $$
From the above equation, its easy to see -  the more $x$ is close to $x_0$, the more its $y$ will have a contribution from $\color{red}{y_0}$ and the less it will have a contribution from $\color{red}{y_1}$. This seems to scale $\color{red}{y_0, y_1}$ values appropriately to get the $y$ values in between. But I'm finding it a bit hard to see this physically on the graph. I've been trying for some relation, using similar triangles etc, to wrap my head around this perspective more strongly.

I'd highly appreciate if you have any alternate ways to show: When $x$ is close to $x_0$, why $\color{red}{y_0}$ contributes more and why $\color{red}{y_1}$ contributes less.

Comment: standard linear interpolation function is $f(t)=(1.0-t)*[x_0,y_0]^{T}+t*[x_1,y_1]^{T}$.

Comment: Ahh nice, vectors. so when $t=0$, it gives $[x_0,y_0]^{T}$ and when $t=1$ it gives $[x_1,y_1]^{T}$. When $t$ is small, $f(t)$ stays more close to $[x_0,y_0]^{T}$ and farther to $[x_1,y_1]^{T}$  . Makes sense... Thank you :)